# Do I need sponsorship from an employer to get a Tier 5 (Youth Mobility Scheme) visa for the UK (from CAD)?

Tags: visas, uk, working-visas

I'm applying for the Tier 5 (Youth Mobility Scheme) visa for the UK. I was under the impression that I did not need a Certificate of Sponsorship/Sponsor number in order to apply (similar to applying for the Working Holiday Visa for Australia).

Upon continuing my application it asks me for my Sponsor Licence Number as shown on my Certificate of Sponsorship.

I am a Canadian, 29 years old. Shouldn't I be able to apply without a sponsor?

Comment: Some nationalities need a sponsor, but not Canadians. Is this an online form and if so is it set as a mandatory question?

Comment: @user16259 It doesn't give me an option to skip. It gives me the following statement:

What is your sponsor licence number as shown on your Certificate of Sponsorship?
(Your sponsor is the organisation you will be working for in the UK, who are sponsoring this application)
_______________________________________________


I click next and it keeps telling me to "enter my employers sponsor licence number. There is no option to skip this step.

Comment: That's odd. Are you definitely on the right page for tier 5 youth mobility and not a different page? If it's an error on the page I can only suggest phoning them during UK office hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, it's a flaw on their update for the new site. I had to use the "old" page for visa applications instead, and that worked.

https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome